# Grid layout - fixed column width and responsive grid-gap

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a layout that fills up the whole horizontal space and the items in the last row are still the same width as other rows thanks to grid layout.

Right now when resizing screen the width of items changes so that the whole row is filled. Is it possible to have the items fixed in width and have the grid-gaps be the ones that adjust?

https://jsfiddle.net/c60ymrfu/

Current CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 20px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

Current behavior:
[image]

Desired behavior:
[image]

Comment: No...CSS-Grid can't do that. Flexbox would be the solution.

Answer (score 8):

You could add some wrapping elements and give a fixed width to the items like so:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 20px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could then position the items in their wrapping parent however you see fit.

Comment: The gap between the most-right item and the edge of the page is changing, so the full width of row is not always taken :/

Comment: You just need to center the items in their parent. Updated the above example to add `margin: auto`.

Comment: Still changing. :/

Answer (score 1):

You could set a fixed item width along with [`justify-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items) or [`place-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items) depending on if you want this to happen in one axis or both:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 20px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  place-items: center;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This also changes the sizes of gaps between left and right edges of the page. :/

Comment: There isn't really a way to fix that and still keep the last row in line with the others.